# How to group my query by name? P_Name

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
select  ID_Sale,SaleDate,Branch_Name,P_Name,P_UnitPrice,QuantitySold,
    sum (QuantitySold*P_UnitPrice) over (order by ID_Sale asc) AS RunningTotal
from tblP_Sales
INNER JOIN tblProduct_With_Img
    ON tblP_Sales.P_ID_Sales = tblProduct_With_Img.P_ID
INNER JOIN tblBranches
    ON tblP_Sales.BranchID = tblBranches.BranchID
--this group is not working ? how to work this ?
  group by P_Name
```

This is the result without the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
Sale_ID Sale_Date   Branch   Item Name                 Pric/unit   qty  RUNTotal

1056    2016-11-10  Ajman   Afghani Pulaw With Meat       26        1   26
1057    2016-11-10  Ajman   Sada Rice With Chicken Boti   24        2   74
1058    2016-11-11  Ajman   Afghani Pulaw With Meat       26        1   100
```

Comment: Code-only questions are difficult to answer. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more. Which 'Name' are you referring to ('Branch_Name', 'P_Name', something else)? Please provide example data if possible.

Comment: same query just group by P_Name    (Product_Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to add "PARTITION BY "

```
select  ID_Sale,SaleDate,Branch_Name,P_Name,P_UnitPrice,QuantitySold,
    sum (QuantitySold*P_UnitPrice) over (PARTITION BY P_Name order by ID_Sale asc) AS RunningTotal
from tblP_Sales
INNER JOIN tblProduct_With_Img
    ON tblP_Sales.P_ID_Sales = tblProduct_With_Img.P_ID
INNER JOIN tblBranches
    ON tblP_Sales.BranchID = tblBranches.BranchID
```

Comment: IT IS GOOD MAKE A GROUP FOR     P_Name i want to group P_Name (Product Name)